# JFree PIE CHART Enhancements

Tags: java, apache, pie-chart

I want to draw Pie_chart for small data set has this form.
[image]

I used these code

```
            DefaultPieDataset my_pie_chart_data = new DefaultPieDataset();  

            for(int i =1; i<9; i++) {
                 row = my_sheet.getRow(0);
                 cell = row.getCell(i);
                    chart_label=cell.getStringCellValue();

                    row = my_sheet.getRow(1);
                    cell = row.getCell(i);
                    chart_data=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    my_pie_chart_data.setValue(chart_label,chart_data);
            }
            JFreeChart myPieChart=ChartFactory.createPieChart("PIE",my_pie_chart_data,true,true,false);

            int width=640; /* Width of the chart */
            int height=480; /* Height of the chart */
            float quality=1; /* Quality factor */

            ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chart_out,quality,myPieChart,width,height);

            int my_picture_id = my_workbook.addPicture(chart_out.toByteArray(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);                

            chart_out.close();

            XSSFDrawing drawing = my_sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

            ClientAnchor my_anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();

            my_anchor.setCol1(4);
            my_anchor.setRow1(5);
            XSSFPicture  my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
            my_picture.resize();
            chart_file_input.close();               
    }
```

the resulting chart has these label on it, which is confusing, specially when the values are small because, they all refer to the same section. And I can live with the legend definition below.
Does anybody know how can I delete them ?

[image]